# I'd like to have duplicated items, all of them (2 or more)

Tags: function, sqlite

I wrote SQLite query like this.

```
myQuery1 = @"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN (
    SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)";
```

It works well.
It gives me all grouped items in case of 2 or more items.

Now, I'd like to make more detailed result.
So, I added myFunction at GROUP BY part.

```
myQuery2 = @"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN (
    SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myFunction(myColumn) 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)";
```

It looks like worked well though, it gives me only 1 result (the last one) when it has grouped 2 or more items.

How can I have all two or more items ?

[EDIT]
"myFunction" is mainly make thing brief.
Something like this.

```
//  Before : "123 Apple"
//  After : "Apple"
```

So, after myFunction, I have only "Letter/Character" part.
So, my duplication could be wider, because I'm ignoring numbers.

It grouped well under "Apple", I guess. But, it gives me only One result.

[EDIT2]
It solve by the nice comment of " Michael Butscher" thanks!!

Comment: Add the `myFunction` code please

Comment: Difficult to say, without knowing what `myFunction` does and without knowing to which data it is applied.

Comment: oh.. that is too long approx.50 lines. Most of them are RegExp. Something like this.(it is C#)    while(Regex.IsMatch(myReturn, "&((amp)|(lt)|(gt)|(quot)|(apos));"))
    myReturn = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(myReturn, "&amp;", "&"),"&lt;", "<"),"&gt;", ">"),"&quot;", @""""),"&apos;", "'");

Comment: I will update main post. thanks

Comment: Try `myQuery2 = @"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myFunction(myColumn) IN (
    SELECT myFunction(myColumn) FROM myTable GROUP BY myFunction(myColumn) 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)";`

Comment: @MichaelButscher woo thanks. I will try out now.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Crazy !!! It works. I've been spend 3 hours for this matter. Thanks a LOT.